Appropriate Research Design for Multiple Independent Variables and Dependent Variables
I need some advice on designing the quantitative aspect of my upcoming master's research project. My research design involves a convergent mixed methods study and aims to explore the factors that disrupt the operations of disabled micro-entrepreneurs divided into different sub-populations. The main goal is to measure the extent of these disruptions within the sub-groups and identify any significant differences.
During my literature review, I found approximately 50 factors that can disrupt these operations, which will serve as my dependent variables. I plan to categorize my participants into several groups, which would become my two independent variables:

Five major economic sectors in which these micro-enterprises are
active.
Seven different types of disabilities.

Since there is no comprehensive list of micro-enterprises owned by disabled individuals, I will use snowball sampling to gather data in my research location.
I have several decisions that I will need to make for this research project, and I would appreciate your feedback and suggestions in this process.
Firstly, the measurement scale for dependent variables. I am considering using either a dichotomous scale (yes/no for each barrier) or an ordinal scale (5-point Likert). Knowing the education level of my participants and my goal of measuring and comparing the prevalence of operational barriers, I am leaning towards a dichotomous scale. However, a Likert scale captures the severity, providing a more nuanced picture of each barrier.
Secondly, I will need to decide how I will analyze the data. If I choose dichotomous measurement, would a chi-square test of homogeneity (r x 2), followed by post hoc testing, be a valid approach? I am concerned about its validity, considering my sampling method. If I use a Likert scale, I am considering a two-way ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis with post-hoc testing. However, I have heard that ANOVA may not be ideal for Likert scale data. Kruskal-Wallis, as far as I have read, is only usable with one independent variables. What would be best, or what other analysis options could I consider?
Thank you for help in advance!

Sorry, but your design needs restructuring.  If your goal is to

explore the factors that disrupt the operations

Then those 50 factors would be independent variables not dependent. Sector and type of disability would also be independent variables. The dependent variable would be "disruption" measured somehow. How that would be measured is up to you, but should reflect both your aims and your literature search. It could be, as you note, dichotomous (disrupted/not) or Likert scale (degree of disruption). This has nothing to do with the educational level of your participants. (There are some other possibilities too, but let's stick with those).
Your analysis should be some form of regression. The natural choices are (binary) logistic regression for a dichotomy or ordinal logistic regression for a Likert scale.
You should also think about how you are going to build your model. 62 IVs is a lot. How will you choose?  Model building is part art and part science and has been discussed here a lot (see variable-selection).
You haven't said what the 50 factors are, but I would bet that there will be some collinearity. How will you explore that and what will you do about it if you find it? This has also been discussed here a lot.
How much data will you have?
Will you stratify by type of disability or include it as a variable?

Hey Peter! Thank you for answering my question and no need to say sorry. I am asking for input, your feedback is valuable to me. Maybe it is good I give a practical example of how a possible survey question would look like?
"I have access to mobile internet services for my micro-enterprise without disruption", which than can be answered using a yes/no or Likert scale. I want to analyze the answers for each sub-population. This would allow me to measure the prevalence within each sub-population. If possible I would also like to measure if there are any significant differences between groups.

Secondly, why I mentioned education level of the participants influencing my preference going towards dichotomous is that I have worked a lot with disabled micro-entrepreneurs as a practitioner, where I have observed that ordinal questions are often difficult for them to answer.
My hope is to gather around 200 surveys.
I will stratify by economic sector and disability type. I guess this would make the major economic sectors and seven types of disability which I will use to divide the groups my controlled variables instead of independent variables, as I mentioned earlier?

You know your participants, but, if they can't answer "a little", "somewhat" ... type of thing, there is a problem.  With only 200 participants you need a MUCH reduced set of variables.  200 in a single disability type would be more reasonable, but even then, you have too many IVs.  And a controlled variable and an independent variable are essentially the same thing.

Finally, I should mention I aim to measure the disruptions disabled micro-entrepreneurs face while operating their businesses from a quantitative and qualitative perspective. The goal is to gain insight into these disruptions to facilitate intervention improvement by highlighting the most common disruptions for sub-populations. My focus is on discovering the prevalence of disruptions within groups, rather than on modeling or predicting the interaction between the obstacles, which is also important, but beyond the scope of my research.

It is definitely a challenging population for research, but that is also what makes it interesting and valuable in my eyes as currently interventions often don't meet their needs.
So, based on your feedback, am I correct in understanding that I should reduce the number of variables and if possible sub-populations in the research and try to make it ordinal if possible? Given my additional comments, would you still recommend using ordinal regression for this research?

Yes to all three questions
